# fix MySQL .SQL script failure - INSERT has an FK column constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqladmin

In `MySQL Workbench 5.2` I am trying to execute a SQL script we have.

How do I actually make the whole thing execute? When I select all and press `ctrl-enter` it only executes one line of the SQL script!

If I execute the script by placing my cursor at the end of the last line; only that last line executes.

I am searching on Google but I guess I do not know how to phrase it correctly or understand enough.

This may be because I moved to a new computer and therefore a new profile. Could it be that MySQL Workbench does not have enough permissions on it?

My only real option seems to be

> > File >> New >> Query Tab

I thought there would be like a new script tab and a new query tab??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `ctrl+shift+enter` or select all the lines in your script file then press `ctrl+enter`

Answer (score 1):

To execute all statements, [hold down the shift key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-keys.html#workbench-keys-menu-query): `Ctri+Shift+Enter`; or click the `Execute` (lightening bolt with neither cursor nor magnifying glass) button on the [toolbar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-toolbar.html); or select `Execute (All or Selection)` from the `Query` [menu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-main-menu.html).